# handleKeyCommand - default fallback function for "space" is not working

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

**Wanted scenario**: typing word followed by  parses word and automatically replaces if matches list of pre-defined abbrevations.

**Implemented how**: custom keyBindingFn property where space creates custom command "cc-space". handleKeyCommand event recognizes "cc-space", evalutes last typed word and does function above.

**Error**: when no match handleKeyCommand returns "not-handled" as recommended in docs to allow "default command", this seems to be ignored as editor never inserts space on let-through while everything else works as expected.

```
import React from "react"
import { Editor, EditorState, SelectionState, Modifier, getDefaultKeyBinding, KeyBindingUtil } from "draft-js"

const myKeyBindingFn = event => {
  const { hasCommandModifier } = KeyBindingUtil
  if (event.keyCode === 32 && !hasCommandModifier(event)) {
    return "cc-space"
  }
  return getDefaultKeyBinding(event)
}

export default class Note extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.handleBeforeInput = this.handleBeforeInput.bind(this)
    this.handleKeyCommand = this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState })
  }

  handleBeforeInput(chars, editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState })
  }

  handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
    console.log("command", command)
    if (command === "cc-space") {
      const selectionState = editorState.getSelection()
      const anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey()
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
      const currentContentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(anchorKey)
      const lastWordEntered = currentContentBlock.getText()

      if (lastWordEntered === "hml") {
        const selectionWord = new SelectionState({
          anchorKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          anchorOffset: 0,
          focusKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          focusOffset: lastWordEntered.length
        })
        const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(contentState, selectionWord, "heimilislæknir ")
        const nextEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, "insert-characters") // editorState.getLastChangeType()
        this.setState({ editorState: nextEditorState }, this.focus)
        return "handled"
      }
    }
    return "not-handled"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        handleBeforeInput={this.handleBeforeInput}
        handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
        keyBindingFn={myKeyBindingFn}
        spellCheck={false}
        autocorrect="off"
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, doesn't matter if "space" or others, just capturing keyCode in myKeyBindingFn and returning other command than default makes fallback function never happen, despite returning "not-handled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use custom key binding function `myKeyBindingFn`, you should provide custom logic to this custom event.

For example, if you remove `return "cc-space"` from your `myKeyBindingFn` space will works correctly.

So, you can define your own logic when user entered space:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Editor,
  EditorState,
  SelectionState,
  Modifier,
  getDefaultKeyBinding,
  KeyBindingUtil
} from "draft-js";

const myKeyBindingFn = event => {
  const { hasCommandModifier } = KeyBindingUtil;

  if (event.keyCode === 32 && !hasCommandModifier(event)) {
    return "cc-space";
  }
  return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
};

export default class Note extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBeforeInput = this.handleBeforeInput.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyCommand = this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  handleBeforeInput(chars, editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
    console.log("command", command);
    if (command === "cc-space") {
      const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
      const anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey();
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      const currentContentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);
      const lastWordEntered = currentContentBlock.getText();

      if (lastWordEntered === "hml") {
        const selectionWord = new SelectionState({
          anchorKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          anchorOffset: 0,
          focusKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          focusOffset: lastWordEntered.length
        });
        const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
          contentState,
          selectionWord,
          "heimilislæknir "
        );
        const nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
          editorState,
          newContentState,
          "insert-characters"
        ); // editorState.getLastChangeType()
        this.setState({ editorState: nextEditorState }, this.focus);
        return "handled";
      } else {
        // There are no any matches.
        // We have to implement custom logic to space:

        const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(
          contentState,
          selectionState,
          " "
        );
        const nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
          editorState,
          newContentState,
          "insert-characters"
        );
        this.setState({ editorState: nextEditorState });
      }
    }
    return "not-handled";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        handleBeforeInput={this.handleBeforeInput}
        handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
        keyBindingFn={myKeyBindingFn}
        spellCheck={false}
        autocorrect="off"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can return `cc-space` event only if it's necessary instead of implementing custom logic to insert space character:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Editor,
  EditorState,
  SelectionState,
  Modifier,
  getDefaultKeyBinding,
  KeyBindingUtil
} from "draft-js";

export default class Note extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBeforeInput = this.handleBeforeInput.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyCommand = this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this);
  }

  // we move this method to class, becouse we have to get this.state.editorState to recognize the last word
  myKeyBindingFn = event => {
    const { hasCommandModifier } = KeyBindingUtil;

    if (event.keyCode === 32 && !hasCommandModifier(event)) {
      const selectionState = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
      const anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey();
      const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
      const currentContentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);
      const lastWordEntered = currentContentBlock.getText();

      if (lastWordEntered === "hml") {
        // return cc-space only if it's necessary
        return "cc-space";
      }
    }
    // in any other cases we return defaultKeyBinding
    return getDefaultKeyBinding(event);
  };

  onChange(editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  handleBeforeInput(chars, editorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }

  handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
    console.log("command", command);
    if (command === "cc-space") {
      const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();
      const anchorKey = selectionState.getAnchorKey();
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      const currentContentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(anchorKey);
      const lastWordEntered = currentContentBlock.getText();

      if (lastWordEntered === "hml") {
        const selectionWord = new SelectionState({
          anchorKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          anchorOffset: 0,
          focusKey: currentContentBlock.getKey(),
          focusOffset: lastWordEntered.length
        });
        const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
          contentState,
          selectionWord,
          "heimilislæknir "
        );
        const nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
          editorState,
          newContentState,
          "insert-characters"
        ); // editorState.getLastChangeType()
        this.setState({ editorState: nextEditorState }, this.focus);
        return "handled";
      }
    }
    return "not-handled";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        handleBeforeInput={this.handleBeforeInput}
        handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
        keyBindingFn={this.myKeyBindingFn}
        spellCheck={false}
        autocorrect="off"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

P.S. `lastWordEntered` has the whole text, not an entered word. Maybe, you want to get only the one word — you can get a solution from here https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/506

Comment: Thank you. Well I got it with introducing a custom handler for key command but as it is conditional I don't understand why "not-handled" doesn't lead to default, fallback handling?

Comment: I think that default handling doesn't work with custom key bindings. 
Consequently, you can change your `myKeyBindingFn` function instead of implementing custom logic in my example.
I appended this example with such case to my answer. So there are two ways to solve this issue

Comment: Having tried many different approaches I think that is the case, with custom binding the fallback is not available, I don't understand what the docs are then refering to for "not-handled".

I ended up using Modifier to insert space my self.

Comment: In draft.js article https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings.html wrote, when you return customKeyBinding event, you should implement your own handleKeyCommand. If you return 'not-handled' in this function you will fall through to default handler behavior. It means, for example, if you implemented your own `ctrl+z` command, handled it in handleKeyCommand function, but returned `not-handled` — draft.js use default handler behavior.

But draft.js will not runs character insertion when you return `not-handled`. So it's works only for default keybindings, not for regular characters

Comment: That seems to be the case yes. Marking as answered. Thank you!

Comment: BTW It seems then logical to move handler code to handleBeforeInput, don't you think?